# Select content from "div class" which contains certain words

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax-response which is generated by a server sided script:

```
<div class="item-title3">Testname</div>
<div class="item-level">120</div>
<div class="item-binding">40</div>
<div class="item-type">Feet</div>
```

Now i want to select the content of the `div class` which contains the `"item-title"` words somewhere in the div class name. So the number in the div class name shouldn´t be relevant (in this case the 3 of item-title3 shouldn´t be relevant).

In this example my code should grab "Testname", but it can´t find it. I think the `siblings` method is the problem here.

```
<script language="javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
  
  $("[tooltip-link]").each(function() {
    let $tooltip = $(this);
    let id = $tooltip.attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        "var": id
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      let $content = $(data);
      let title = $content.siblings('.item-title').text()

      $tooltip.tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "test",
        content: data
      });

       $("<div class=\"item-title\">" + title + "</div>").appendTo($tooltip);
    });
  });
    
});
</script>

<a tooltip-link data-id="12555" title=""></a>
```

Comment: If you have control of the HTML, just add a common class to all those elements then select by that, eg. `class="item-title item-title3"`. I'd also suggest moving away from incremental id/class attributes as they are an anti-pattern which lead to needlessly complex code.

Comment: Hi did you tried like this : `$content.siblings('[class^=item-title]').text()` ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use **jQuery wildcard** class selector which contains **item-title** string.

```html
<div class='hidden' style='display:none'></div>
```

```js
let $content = $.parseHTML(data);
$('.hidden').empty();
$('.hidden').append($content);
$('.hidden').find('div[class*=item-title]').text();
```

Add one extra hidden div which holds the html response and use $.parseHTML method to parse the response string to html and append it to the hidden div. Make sure every time clear the hidden div content.

Wildcard selector selects elements which matches the string specified in the class attribute.

Comment: Stupid question, but how do I use my `$content` variable inside of that code? `let title = $content('div[class*=item-title]').text()` doesn´t works.

Comment: Updated answer please check.

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error in the console: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"`

Comment: @Berstos Please share jsfiddle for the same. Need to check your response(data).